# How to split batch file & take the first item

Tags: batch-file, split

I having application version for example 15.0.45.577

How can I split the string by (.) to take only version 15 need to create a dynamic path like:

set version = 15 <- here I need to create the split on the string

c:\%version%\15.0.45.577

tried the following example, but it's not working for me.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=. TOKENS=1" %i IN (%myString%) DO ECHO %i\%j
```

Comment: You got what you defined. `TOKENS=1` results in one token, not two. You could try `TOKENS=1,2,3,4` or `TOKENS=1-4`

Comment: You should be using `("%myString%")`